# Drawing median and quartile lines on an Altair violin plot

Tags: python, plot, altair

Suppose I had the following plot (taken from the [tutorial](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/violin_plot.html) in the Altair documentation):

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.cars()).transform_density(
    'Miles_per_Gallon',
    as_=['Miles_per_Gallon', 'density'],
    extent=[5, 50],
    groupby=['Origin']
).mark_area(orient='horizontal').encode(
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N',
    x=alt.X(
        'density:Q',
        stack='center',
        impute=None,
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, values=[0],grid=False, ticks=True),
    ),
    column=alt.Column(
        'Origin:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelPadding=0,
        ),
    )
).properties(
    width=100
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

[image: violin_plot]

How would I got about drawing quartile and median lines on each of those violin plots? Would I have to define another plot and layer it on top of the violin plots? It would also be nice if the lines are the same width as the violin plot at the specific location on the distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would layer them before faceting. It get a little tricky with what needs to be added to the layered and the faceted chart respectively, but something like this would work:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

violins = alt.Chart().transform_density(
    'Miles_per_Gallon',
    as_=['Miles_per_Gallon', 'density'],
    extent=[5, 50],
    groupby=['Origin']
).mark_area(orient='horizontal').encode(
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N',
    x=alt.X(
        'density:Q',
        stack='center',
        impute=None,
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, values=[0],grid=False, ticks=True),
    ),
)

alt.layer(
    violins,
    alt.Chart().mark_rule().encode(
        y='median(Miles_per_Gallon)',
        x=alt.X(),
        color=alt.value('black')),
).properties(
    width=100
).facet(
    data=data.cars(),
    column=alt.Column(
        'Origin:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelPadding=0,
        ),
    )
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

[image]

Then you can do the same for the quartiles. I am not sure how you would limit the lines to the width of the area other than manually putting in the values,  and I think that would be a bit tricky as well. I would suggest putting a boxplot inside the violin instead:

```py
alt.layer(
    violins,
    alt.Chart().mark_boxplot(size=5, extent=0, outliers=False).encode(
        y='Miles_per_Gallon',
        x=alt.value(46),
        color=alt.value('black')
    )
).properties(
    width=100
).facet(
    data=data.cars(),
    column=alt.Column(
        'Origin:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelPadding=0,
        ),
    )
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

[image]

This is similar to [how seaborn handles violinplots by default](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) and it is also how they were described in [the original paper by Hintze and Nelson in 1997](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1998.10480559).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice! I would agree actually, a box plot would be more helpful.

Comment: How did you arrive at alt.value(46) for the x coordinate of the boxplot layer?

Comment: @lrthistlethwaite I don't recall fully but I believe it was just trial and error until it looked like the plot was centered. When Vega-Lite/Altair gets appropriate support for violin plots, there will be less fiddling like this required https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3442#issuecomment-1098023693

Answer (score 0):

A small update in addition to @joelostblom's great answer. It is possible to align the violins and box plots without "magic numbers." The way I did it was *two* mirrored density plots.

```py
data = cars

violin_right = (
    alt.Chart(data, width=100)
    .transform_density(
        "Miles_per_Gallon",
        as_=["Miles_per_Gallon", "density"],
        extent=[5, 50],
        groupby=["Origin"]
    )
    .mark_area(orient="horizontal")
    .encode(
        alt.X("density:Q")
            .impute(None)
            .title(None)
            .axis(labels=False, grid=False, ticks=True),
        alt.Y("Miles_per_Gallon:Q"),
        alt.Color("Origin:N")
    )
)

violin_left = (
    violin_right
    .copy()
    .transform_calculate(density="-datum.density")
)

boxplot = (
    alt.Chart(data, width=100)
    .mark_boxplot(outliers=False, size=5, extent=1.5)
    .encode(y="Miles_per_Gallon:Q", color=alt.value("black"))
)

chart = (
    alt.layer(violin_left, violin_right, boxplot)
    .facet(alt.Column("Origin:N"))
    .configure_view(stroke=None)
)
```

The created `chart` looks as follows.

[image: Violin plot with quartiles]

The vertical axes of the violins and boxes are nicely centered at zero point.